# A script to automatically delete folders in another folder

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, directory

I've came across several posts and even code online about .batch files to delete folders and files. However, I am still pretty confused by the myriad amount of information that's on the Internet. Is there a specific way of writing a script that automatically deletes folders that are older than 30 days (the script has to be smart enough to run itself and not be done manually)

I appreciate your help and I am willing to learn here. Thanks!

P.S. I've attached an example of the kind of folders that I would like to delete. As you can see these folders date back to 2008

[image]

Comment: Which folders to delete? All??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove the entire directory tree, so use it with coution and remove the `echo`, if the output is OK:

```
forfiles /d -30  /c "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE echo rd /s /q @fname"
```

Answer (score 1):

Scripts can not run them selves automatically, but the os provides facilities to do that using scheduled tasks.  So you need to create yourself a batch file to delete what you need and then add a recurring scheduled task to do the work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in batch command to work only on files with a certain age. But you can download the [forfiles tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc753551%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) from Microsoft. It allows to execute commands on files of a certain age only (on the command line).